# Why is ivar not found if getter is present in obj-c class?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a very simple class `ExampleTrack` with the property `duration`. I want to implement the getter and setter for this property on my own. My problem is that I get compiler errors, which claim _duration (the ivar) is undeclared. Here is my code:

ExampleTrack.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ExampleTrack : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) Float32 duration;

@end
```

ExampleTrack.m

```
#import "ExampleTrack.h"

@implementation ExampleTrack

-(void)setDuration:(Float32)duration {
    _duration = duration; // compiler error: Use of undeclared identifier '_duration'; did you mean 'duration'?
}

-(Float32)duration {
    return _duration; // compiler error: Use of undeclared identifier '_duration'
}

@end
```

The most interesting part is that if I remove the getter, then the setter compiles fine.

What's wrong here?

Comment: It won't work if you write both the getter and setter, you can easily solve it by adding `@synthesize  duration = _duration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tricky, because the rules for *automatic naming* of the automatically synthesized instance variable change depending on the circumstances.

- If you have no getter or setter and no explicit `@synthesize`, but just let everything be synthesized automatically, then (nowadays) a property named `prop` gets an ivar `_prop`.
- But if you provide the getter and setter yourself and no explicit `@synthesize`, then *nothing* happens automatically: in particular, the ivar is not auto synthesized (you must declare the ivar explicitly). This is partly for backwards compatibility and partly because if you are providing both a getter and a setter the compiler assumes you are in (and want) full control. There might not even be an ivar in this situation; the getter/setter could be a "front" to something else entirely.

There are two "solutions" (assuming that you want to keep both the getter and the setter):

- Declare the ivar. You can name the ivar anything you like, and you can refer to it in your getter and setter (I like the `self->_ivar` syntax).
- Write an explicit `@synthesize` statement. This allows you to specify the name of the ivar that the compiler will create for you.

Comment: And see my full discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_accessor_synthesis Even I have to consult this sometimes!